# How does one use `sqlx` with `juniper` subscriptions in Rust?

Tags: rust, graphql, juniper, rust-sqlx

**Background:**

I am having trouble integrating `sqlx` with `juniper` subscriptions.

I am getting a `Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Result<User, sqlx::Error>> + 'e + Send>>` from [`sqlx::query::QueryAs::fetch()`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.4.1/sqlx/query/struct.QueryAs.html#method.fetch).

`juniper` needs [subscriptions](https://graphql-rust.github.io/juniper/master/advanced/subscriptions.html) to be returned as `Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Result<User, juniper::FieldError>> + Send>>`.

Note the change from `Result<User, sqlx::Error>` to `Result<User, juniper::FieldError>`. Using [`map_err()` from `futures::TryStreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.8/futures/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#method.map_err), I created the following code to perform the query and transform the error type.

```rust
type UsersStream =
    Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Result<User, FieldError>> + Send>>;

#[juniper::graphql_subscription(Context = Context)]
impl SubscriptionRoot {
    async fn users(context: &Context) -> UsersStream {
        let sqlx::query_as!(User, "SELECT * FROM users")
            .fetch(&context.pool)
            .map_err(|e| {
                FieldError::new(
                    "Database error",
                    graphql_value!(format!("{}", e)))
            })
            .boxed()
    }
}
```

This fails with the following error on compile:

```
error[E0759]: `executor` has lifetime `'ref_e` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> server/src/graphql/subscription.rs:27:1
   |
27 |   #[juniper::graphql_subscription(Context = Context)]
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |   |
   |   this data with lifetime `'ref_e`...
   |   ...is captured here...
...
63 | /         sqlx::query_as!(User, "SELECT * FROM users")
64 | |             .fetch(&context.pool)
65 | |             .map_err(|e| {
66 | |                 FieldError::new(
...  |
69 | |             })
70 | |             .boxed()
   | |____________________- ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
   |
   = note: this error originates in an attribute macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I am not familiar enough with `Stream`s or lifetimes to understand the implications of this error. After looking into this some more, it seems that [`ref_e`](https://github.com/graphql-rust/juniper/blob/cd66bdb/juniper/src/types/subscriptions.rs#L115) is the lifetime of the subscription's reference to `juniper`'s `Executor`.

**Attempts:**

- Providing a lifetime to `juniper::Context` as discussed in [graphql-rust/juniper#143](https://github.com/graphql-rust/juniper/issues/143).
- Higher-ranked trait bounds

**Versions:**

- `sqlx-0.4.1`
- `juniper` pinned to commit `cd66bdb` on `master`

Comment: I actually just finished implementing a toy graphql server for a personal project and decided not to use sqlx because I could not integrate it either, so I am looking forward to this answer. I would say it'd be beneficial to also post how your Context looks like because I had some "borrow check" issues when defining mine.

Comment: @fvall what did you use instead of sqlx ?

Comment: I've made a small repository to reproduce the problem : https://github.com/mathroc/juniper-sqlx-subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

your code is not exactly like mine but I think the solution can apply here too, try to clone the pool before using it:

```rust
type UsersStream =
    Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Result<User, FieldError>> + Send>>;

#[juniper::graphql_subscription(Context = Context)]
impl SubscriptionRoot {
    async fn users(context: &Context) -> UsersStream {
        let pool = context.pool.clone();
        let sqlx::query_as!(User, "SELECT * FROM users")
            .fetch(&pool)
            .map_err(|e| {
                FieldError::new(
                    "Database error",
                    graphql_value!(format!("{}", e)))
            })
            .boxed()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Mathieu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69851785/472784) is correct. So I'll explain the reason behind the error.

The fundamental issue here is when you're returning `UsersStream` you're moving data out of the function `fn users(..)`. Now the caller of the function `users(..)` owns the returned data and (theoretically) can do whatever it wants to do, including keeping the data for the lifetime of the application, i.e. giving the data 'static lifetime. But if `UsersStream` has a reference to a data (`context.pool`) with a limited lifetime, what'll happen when the owner of `pool` drops the data? It'll refer to nullpointer as data is dropped. So the compiler throws errors to prevent such a situation.

So what you can do here is to somehow pass the owned data(`pool`) instead of reference, ensuring that `pool` has the same lifetime as `UsersStream` as it owns the data now. `clone()` does exactly this, it creates an owned copy(either reference-counted or byte copy) of the data.